# Assign additional variables to the component returned by React.memo and getting automatic type inference working

Tags: reactjs, typescript

If I assign additional variables to a regular function, TypeScript will automatically infer the properties that I explicitly declare. However, if I assign additional variables to the component returned by React.memo, TypeScript cannot automatically infer those properties that I explicitly declare.

```
// how I assign extra variables to Foo = React.memo(foo), just like assign to foo?
// and get infer typing working just like foo?
const Foo = React.memo(foo)

Foo.cssset = {
  root: css``,
  bar: css``,
}

Foo.cssset // expect toBe { root: number, bar: number }
  //^?
Foo.cssset.root // expect toBe number
         //^?
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WPB5LN)

2023/08/10 updated:

I hope to configure some static properties in foo, such as declaring CSS classNames that will only be used within the foo component, as shown in the following example:

```
const foo = () => {
  <div css={[foo.cssset.root]}>
  <div css={[foo.cssset.areas.filter]}>
    <SimulatedButton />
    <SymbolSelector />
  </div>

  <div css={[foo.cssset.areas.status]}>
    <OverviewsStatus />
  </div>

  <div css={[foo.cssset.areas.list]}>
    <DataList />
  </div>
</div>
}

export const Foo = React.memo(foo)

foo.cssset = {
  root: 'root-fj289uf',
  areas: {
    filter: 'filter-fjiu128',
    status: 'filter-fkj2if8',
    list: 'filter-vjk38f',
  },
}
```

And furthermore, to allow designers to simply remember the component names and access everything they need for their designs directly from within the components.

```
<div
  id='layout'
  css={css`
    .${foo.cssset.root} {
      //  ^I want using Foo.cssset, not foo.cssset
      // designer changes the css style
    }
  `}
></div>
```

Achieving this can be done by assigning variables to foo, but it might require designers to import an additional variable. Moreover, when wrapping foo with React.memo, the process might not be as smooth or straightforward.

So, what I'm actually hoping for is this, and to allow designers to effortlessly access the variables they need with minimal effort.

```
export const Foo = React.memo(() => {
  return <div css={[foo.cssset.root]}>
    <div css={[foo.cssset.areas.filter]}>
      <SimulatedButton />
      <SymbolSelector />
    </div>

    <div css={[foo.cssset.areas.status]}>
      <OverviewsStatus />
    </div>

    <div css={[foo.cssset.areas.list]}>
      <DataList />
    </div>
  </div>
})

Foo.cssset = {
  root: 'root-fj289uf',
  areas: {
    filter: 'filter-fjiu128',
    status: 'filter-fkj2if8',
    list: 'filter-vjk38f',
  },
}
```

designer:

```
<div
  id='layout'
  css={css`
    .${Foo.cssset.root} {
      // designer changes the css style
    }
  `}
></div>
```

Comment: TypeScript won't let you assign `cssset` to `Foo` because it doesn't satisfy the type returned by `React.memo`. There are ways to get around it but this has smells of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) because doing this is unusual. What problem are you trying to solve by attempting this?

Comment: I heard about the XY problem for the first time, and I learned what it means. I'm sorry, my question was indeed a case of the XY problem. I've learned from this experience and I'll be more careful in my future questions. If you have more tips about asking questions, please feel free to share them with me.

Comment: Why not just wrap React.memo https://tsplay.dev/w6V2Rw

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I tried your solution, but it didn't work for me. What I'm hoping for is the ability to define Foo.cssset after React.memo(foo). In the version you adjusted for me, there was a misunderstanding since I had already defined foo.cssset = { root, bar } above. I apologize for the confusion. Here is the correct version where the type cannot be inferred: https://tsplay.dev/WPB5LN

Comment: What's the thinking behind assigning as static properties to the component? It sounds like you're trying to build a design system and there's already some really good patterns out there. For examples, see [Theme UI](https://theme-ui.com) ([spec](https://theme-ui.com/theme-spec), [examples](https://theme-ui.com/resources)) and Google Material's [Design Tokens](https://m3.material.io/foundations/design-tokens/overview). I do realise, this isn't an answer to your question, however I'm trying to make sure the reasoning behind the decisions you've made are solid.